# Can you upload binary files to RAM?

Tags: ram, storage, data-storage, log

Let's say I wanted to create a music midi dapp player where I store all the .midi files in RAM or should I store it in the blockchain (log?).

Example: http://www.midishrine.com/index.php?id=85

Let's say I wanted to upload one of the midi files there, the 2.2KB one.

- How much would it cost to store in RAM vs LOG?
- How do you upload a file like that? Which wallets support it? What is the cleos command?
- How would one retrieve it back?
- Can one retrieve it back via one of the block explorers?
- What else might I be missing to make this work?
- And last, compared to ethereum, how much would it cost to do it there vs EOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely should not use RAM for binary data unless it's literally very few bytes.
The RAM cost will be prohibitive.
And just imagine it in scale: the current available amount of RAM can store only a few HD videos.

It is my understanding that, whenever you need binary data, you use some third-party way to store the data itself, and just store and URL and hash of the data on the blockchain.

Comment: that requires 2 separate services or blockchains. which means double authentication. I wanted to keep everything under the same roof.

Comment: @Patoshiパトシ Understandable, but the costs outweigh the benefit. We can use a microscope to hammer nails, or store HD movies in our local computer's RAM, just to have one tool do all jobs. But it's better to bring a hammer, or store movies on a hard disk, respectively.

Comment: EOS storage was proposed but is not yet available. That would solve the two authentication problem.